# Accessing the content of a List of private type got from reflection

Tags: c#

By `methodInfo.Invoke` I get an `object` which is of type `List<ToBeReflected+SomePrivateClassInsideIt>` which I know from when I tried to `ToString` the `object`.

I want to access the data inside this `object`. I could not cast to the list of said class because that class is private but I do know its variable names. How can I enumerate this list and access its content?

```
public class ToBeReflected
{
    private static List<SomePrivateClassInsideIt> ReflectThis => new List<SomePrivateClassInsideIt>();

    private class SomePrivateClassInsideIt
    {
        public readonly List<int> Ints;
        public int num1;
        public int num2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic `List` implements non-generic `IEnumerable`, thus you can cast list object to `IEnumerable` to iterate over it.

Note that I changed `ReflectThis` from

```
private static List<SomePrivateClassInsideIt> ReflectThis
    => new List<SomePrivateClassInsideIt>();
```

to

```
private static List<SomePrivateClassInsideIt> ReflectThis { get; }
    = new List<SomePrivateClassInsideIt>();
```

Otherwise you will always receive empty list.
Then during iteration over `IEnumerable` you reflect objects in collection using normal way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object reflectThis = typeof(ToBeReflected).GetProperty("ReflectThis", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
            int objIndex = 0;
            foreach(object obj in (reflectThis as IEnumerable))
            {
                Type objType = obj.GetType();
                List<int> ints = (List<int>)objType.GetField("Ints", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj);
                int num1 = (int)objType.GetField("num1", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj);
                int num2 = (int)objType.GetField("num2", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(obj);
                Console.WriteLine("Object #" + objIndex);
                Console.WriteLine("  Ints: " + string.Join(",", ints));
                Console.WriteLine("  num1: " + num1);
                Console.WriteLine("  num2: " + num2);
                objIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ToBeReflected
    {
        private static List<SomePrivateClassInsideIt> ReflectThis { get; } = new List<SomePrivateClassInsideIt>();

        private class SomePrivateClassInsideIt
        {
            public readonly List<int> Ints;
            public int num1;
            public int num2;

            public SomePrivateClassInsideIt(List<int> ints)
            {
                Ints = ints;
            }
        }

        static ToBeReflected()
        {
            ReflectThis.Add(new SomePrivateClassInsideIt(new List<int> { 0, 1 }) { num1 = 2, num2 = 3 });
            ReflectThis.Add(new SomePrivateClassInsideIt(new List<int> { 4, 5 }) { num1 = 6, num2 = 7 });
        }
    }
}
```